# Error - custom transitions require both a fromViewController and toViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I am attempting to dismiss one view controller from the presenting view controller and the upon completion handler of the dismiss, attempting to pop the presenting view controller from the navigation stack.

I receive this error:

`custom transitions require both a fromViewController and toViewController!`

What does this error mean?

If I attempt to call both dismiss of the presented view controller and pop of the navigation controller's current view controller, I receive a different error message:

`[_UIViewControllerOneToOneTransitionContext _setPresentationStyle:]: message sent to deallocated instance`

Comment: some more code would be useful.

Comment: Is it important that you animate through each view, or are you just trying to get all the way back to the original view?

Comment: I just tried separating the two transitions into two separate custom transition objects (I was using the same object for both transitions).  This seems to have fixed the problem.